# Using git tfs with Plastic SCM Git Sync

Tags: git, plasticscm

Since Plastic SCM talks the Git Protocol, is it possible to configure Plastic to use the "plugins" already available to git?

I mean, I can use the:

```
git tfs <parameters here>
```

to make git and tfs synced. I just don't want to keep a git in the way. :)

Comment: Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576313/using-plasticscm-or-any-dvcs-client-to-connect-to-tfs/16589120#16589120